# How to get value of different input hidden value with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get one value of all input when i click to link using jquery and the library fancybox. 
For example:

```
HTML
<input="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="205" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="205">
<div class="txtpuesto">TEXT ONE</a>
<input="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="206" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="206">
<div class="txtpuesto">TEXT TWO</a>
<input="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="207" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="207">
<div class="txtpuesto">TEXT THREE</a>

JQUERY
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Txt;
  $(".fichapuesto").fancybox({
    onStart: function(){
        var Txt = $("#numficha").val();
        return { href : 'infor.php?nro='+ encodeURI(Txt) }
    },
    type: 'iframe',
    width : 1100,
    height: 700,
    });
});
function resizeFancyBox(){  .... }
```

Can you help me to how get one value to href link?

Regards.

Comment: try `$(this).prev('input:hidden').val()`

Answer (score 0):

> Can you help me to how get one value to href link?

First you need **valid html**.  Your *anchor tag* need closing tags. There is no html tag `input="hidden"`, so I'll assume you meant `input type="hidden"`.

To get the value of the *anchor tag* you'll want to use jQuerys [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fichapuesto').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.data('value');
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="205" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="205">
  <div class="txtpuesto">TEXT ONE</div>
</a>

<input type="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="206" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="206">
  <div class="txtpuesto">TEXT TWO</div>
</a>

<input type="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="207" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="207">
  <div class="txtpuesto">TEXT THREE</div>
</a>
```

If you want the corresponding input element based on your current html, you can use the value in a selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fichapuesto').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.data('value');
    var $input = $('input[value="' + value + '"]');
    console.log($input.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="205" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="205">
  <div class="txtpuesto">TEXT ONE</div>
</a>

<input type="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="206" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="206">
  <div class="txtpuesto">TEXT TWO</div>
</a>

<input type="hidden" name="numficha[]" value="207" />
<a class='fichapuesto' data-value="207">
  <div class="txtpuesto">TEXT THREE</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

give them id's and use selectors.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Answer (score -2):

in that case do so

```
<input="hidden" id="nficha" name="numficha[]" value="205" />

jQuery 
 var Txt = $("#numficha").val();
```

Comment: Jquery: var Txt = $("#nficha").val();